# Issue when sideloading todo-list-with-Azure-backend sample code, I get the following error:

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

When I attempt to sideload the todo-list-with-Azure-Backend into my desktop teams client, I get the following error (The code compiles and deploys okay to my Azure tenant), Am I missing a permission somewhere?
[image]

Comment: Could you please share more info and the sample code you are referring to ?

Comment: Here is the error message I get on the console when trying to access the app, so this does look like a deployment issue.  I tried teamsfx decploy from CLI and from the command prompt, neither worked.
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://local.teams.office.com/sourcemaps/hashed-assets/fluentui-cbad7a14703fe351.js.map: Connection error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
todolistfeb680aa.z13.web.core.windows.net/index.html#/config:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (The requested content does not exist.)

Comment: Go to the path:
C:\Users\YOURNAME\node_modules
and then remove those packages which show an error.

Comment: You can refer to this , where its being discussed: https://github.com/creativetimofficial/argon-dashboard-react/issues/28

Comment: With Prasad-MSFT's instruction, has this issue been fixed?

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a deployment issue.  I can provision the app fine but when I run teamsfx deploy, I get the following error: "The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency: babel-jest:^26.6.0"

The instructions to fix it might be missing a step because they don't work.  So my app isn't deploying correctly.

Comment: You should edit the question and include additional steps and information in it. That is preferable in this case over posting a partial answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is solved. I was running the build on a Macintosh.  I don't believe the developer tools for Teams run on a Mac.  Anyway, when I switched to my Windows machine, the app loaded correctly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - I was running the build on a Mac which I believe does not support Teams Developer Preview.  When I switched to my Windows machine, it works fine